# Align TikZ Word Overlays

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using TikZ to produce 'highlights' over individual words as follows:

```
\newcommand*\hl[1]{\tikz[overlay]\node[draw, fill={rgb:black,1;red,5}, 
  inner sep=1mm, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, 
  minimum height=8mm] {#1};\phantom{#1}}

\hl{Word} \hl{one}, \hl{another} \hl{long} \hl{phrase}.
```

[image]

As you can see, although the sentence is aligned, the highlights themselves are not. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14):

Add a `\strut` to each `\hl`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\hl[1]{\tikz[overlay]\node[draw, fill={rgb:black,1;red,5}, 
  inner sep=1mm, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, 
  minimum height=8mm] {#1\strut};\phantom{#1}}
\begin{document}

\Huge \hl{Word} \hl{one}, \hl{another} \hl{long} \hl{phrase}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might be able to tighten it up a bit by reducing the `inner sep` value, or else with a custom strut, such as

```
\def\mystrut{\rule[-.5\dp\strutbox]{0pt}{.75\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}}
```

and then use `\mystrut` in the `\hl` definition.

Answer (score 5):

Just another solution with `tcolorbox` instead of `TikZ`.

`on line` option aligns all boxes to their baseline and doesn't create new paragraphs between them.

`before upper=\strut` assures same height for all boxes.

In this case `size=small` fixes all box margins and border width, but if necessary any particular margin can be fixed independently.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{hl}{size=small, colback=red!90!black, 
    on line, before upper=\strut}

\begin{document}
\hl{Word} \hl{one}, \hl{another} \hl{long} \hl{phrase}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could add `text depth` to also account for this possible length. To avoid the overlapping I suggest also adding `inner xsep` and specify a suitable value there to avoid overlapping of the boxes.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \newcommand*\hl[1]{%
        \tikz[overlay]%
            \node [
                draw,
                fill={rgb:black,1;red,5},
                inner sep=1mm,
                inner xsep=0.2ex,   % <-- added
                anchor=text,
                rectangle,
                rounded corners=1mm,
%                minimum height=8mm,
                text height=2ex,
                text depth=1ex,     % <-- added
            ] {#1}
        ;%
            \phantom{#1}%
    }
\begin{document}
    \hl{Word} \hl{one}, \hl{another} \hl{long} \hl{phrase}.
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 4):

Add a `\vphantom{gh}` to your `\hl` macro. That is because you have different kinds of letters; some with more depth down the baseline and others with more height. So, we choose one from each group to have the same text height in all cases. Also, `8mm` is an absolute measure which may not suit certain font sizes, so, some `fontsize` dependent measure like `minimum height=1em` would be better.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\hl[1]{\tikz[overlay]\node[draw, fill={rgb:black,1;red,5}, 
  inner sep=1pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, 
  minimum height=1em] {#1\vphantom{gh}};\phantom{#1}}
\begin{document}

\hl{Word} \hl{one}, \hl{another} \hl{long} \hl{phrase}.

\end{document}
```

[image]