# How to Contiguously Shade a Portion of a Paragraph with Color

Tags: pdftex, color, paragraphs, mdframed, highlighting

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\colorlet{soulred}{red!25}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\begingroup
  \sethlcolor{soulred}%
  Here is some text. \hl{Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.  Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.}%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

producing the output

[image]

QUESTION: I would like to have no white space showing between the red highlighting; but rather, have the displayed highlighted text appear as a "color-filled polygon." What might be the best way to accomplish this; and how? My MWE may not be the best way to start. *Remark:* I know that if I wanted the entire paragraph "blocked off", I could use the `mdframed` package, but I don't know how to extend  it to a specific portion(s) of a given paragraph. I compiled the code with `pdflatex`. Thank you.

Comment: It would seem that soul goes to some effort to put those white gaps between the lines.  It doesn't increase the line spacing, but `\hl{...}` does redefine `\strut` and `\rule`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm not sure exactly what you mean. In light of your comment and the post  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301432/align-tikz-word-overlays/301433#301433, (figuring that I might be able to adjust the thickness of the highlighting and eliminate the undesired white-line space)---I am unfortunately, unable to "break" the highlighting to resemble an ordinary paragraph. Perhaps you might consider elaborating a little more in the form of an answer. Thank you for the information you provided.

Comment: see also this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex

Comment: I was trying to find a simple solution by reducing the line spacing or increase the size of the highlighted area, but nothing I tried worked.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59340/how-to-highlight-an-entire-paragraph for a rather complete set of alternatives.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am familiar with those answers; however, they address entire 
 paragraphs only, not partial ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses `\tikzmark` to locate the start and end of the highlighted area.  Each `\tikzmark` requires a unique name. These are stored on the aux file, so it takes two runs to locate them.

Note that the tikzpicture comes before the text.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{soulred}{red!25}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\newlength{\markheight}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\coordinate (A) at (pic cs:start);
\coordinate (B) at (pic cs:end);
\pgfextracty{\markheight}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}}% difference in baselines
\ifdim\markheight<\baselineskip% same line
  \fill[color=soulred] ($(A)+(-2pt,\ht\strutbox)$) rectangle ($(B)+(2pt,-\dp\strutbox)$);
\else
  \ifdim\markheight<3\baselineskip
    \fill[color=soulred] ($(A)+(-2pt,\ht\strutbox)$) rectangle ($(A -| current page text area.east)+(2pt,-\dp\strutbox)$);
    \fill[color=soulred] ($(B -| current page text area.west)+(-2pt,\ht\strutbox)$) rectangle ($(B)+(2pt,-\dp\strutbox)$);
  \else
    \fill[color=soulred] ($(A)+(-2pt,\ht\strutbox)$) rectangle ($(A -| current page text area.east)+(2pt,-\dp\strutbox)$);
    \fill[color=soulred] ($(A -| current page text area.west)+(-2pt,-\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle ($(B -| current page text area.east)+(2pt,\ht\strutbox)$);
    \fill[color=soulred] ($(B -| current page text area.west)+(-2pt,\ht\strutbox)$) rectangle ($(B)+(2pt,-\dp\strutbox)$);
  \fi
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}

  Here is some text. \tikzmark{start}Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.  Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.\tikzmark{end}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Many thanks John Kormylo!